# How to create a Dockerfile that installs git and jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

**Background info**

I plan to create two containers.

Container 1 will have Jenkins and Git installed. The purpose of having Git installed with Jenkins is so I can retrieve my git repository in the "Select pipeline script from scm" section in a pipeline job. The container needs to have access to Git.

Container 2 will have all the dependencies for my .NET Windows application installed (MSBuild, Wix, Nuget, .NET frameworks, etc.).

**Challenge**
For container 1, how do I install Git if my base image is jenkins:latest. I tried using apt-get and apk add. Those obviously don't work since my base image is not ubuntu or alpine...

I expect downloading the packages in container 2 will be a lot easier since I would just use the ubuntu base image.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Jenkins's [dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile),  it  looks like git is pre-installed  for  you.

For  challenge 2,  since you're using a ubuntu image, it's just the same as installing .Net  dependencies on  a ubuntu  machine.

Comment: I searched online and could not find the .NET packages on a ubuntu machine. I think I need to use a Windows container. Using the microsoft/windowsservercore base image, I would install all of my packages through chocolatey. Is it possible for Jenkins (Linux container) to create a windows container (image with all .NET dependencies)? How else would I download my .NET packages on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

When I pull and run this jenkins image jenkins:2.60.3, git was pre-installed in it.

```
$ git version
git version 2.11.0
```

Hope this image might help you.